# Keywords `in, out, ref` vs Attributes `[In], [Out], [In, Out]`

Tags: c#, marshalling

I know that the first set of keywords `in, out, ref` can be used in all C# functions, and the second set of attributes `[In], [Out], [In, Out]` is for marshaller.

I am not sure if they mean the same thing when used in function declaration of native code. For example, are the following two declarations equivalent?

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll")]
void FillArray1(ref int[] arr, in int length);

[DllImport("xxx.dll")]
void FillArray2([In, Out] int[] arr, [In] int length);
```

Are there any case that the two sets are not equivalent?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what `In` or `Out` attributes do, but keywords `in` and `out` are checked at compile time (for read-only/write-only accesses) and also parameter is passed as reference, not as value. Attributes in general can be queried via reflection at run-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

For the `ref int[] arr` the default `[In, Out]` attributes will be applied automatically, but it is still not the same as `[In, Out] int[] arr`.

`ref int[] arr` is a double indirection (a reference type passed by reference). Use this if the native side is defined something like this: `int32_t** arr`. This allows to replace not just the elements but the whole array instance as well.

On the other hand, `[In, Out] int[] arr` is a simple reference passed by value. Use this if the native side also uses single indirection, eg. `int32_t* arr`. Normally in C# if you pass an array by value (which is a reference type) the called method can replace the elements, which will be reflected from the caller side. However, P/Invoke marshaling works a bit [differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/77e6taeh%28v%3Dvs.100%29):

> By default, reference types (classes, arrays, strings, and interfaces) passed by value are marshaled as `In` parameters for performance reasons. You do not see changes to these types unless you apply `InAttribute` and `OutAttribute` (or just `OutAttribute`) to the method parameter.

So the native side gets a correct pointer regardless of specifying the `Out` attribute. Specifying `[Out]` here is needed for the marshaler so it will not omit the copy-back session to the managed memory.

Similarly, `in int length` will pass a reference to an integer and is not the same as `[In] int length`, which passes the parameter simply by value. The `[In]` can be omitted as this is the default marshaling behavior in this case.